# If someone won a match now what should be used?

Tags: grammar

If someone won a match now what should be used? I know both are fine but using past simple I think it does not tell when he won, right now or sometime ago in past, or should for recent past we use now?
 He has won the tennis match.
He won the tennis match.

Answer (score 0):

I would say

> *He just won the tennis match.*

or

> *He has just won the tennis match.*